# How can I remove a specific node based on its keyvalue?

Tags: xml, powershell

The task is to remove a node based on either key or value, for e.g the whole entry with key "org.quartz.B" and value="BBB" should be removed.

```
<config>
 <module>
   <section name="java">
    <entry key="org.quartz.A" value="AAA" />
    <entry key="org.quartz.B" value="BBB" />
    <entry key="org.quartz.C" value="CCC" />
    <entry key="org.quartz.D" value="false" />
   </section>
    <section name="db">
    <entry key="oracle" value="12" />
    <entry key="mssql" value="2012" />
    <entry key="mysql" value="6.1" />       
   </section>
 </module>
</config>
```

Code which i have tried is

```
$getxmlpath="C:\test.xml"
$xml=[xml](Get-Content $getxmlpath)
Write-Host ($xml)
$javasection = $xml.config.module | where-Object {$_.name -eq 'java'}
Write-Host ($javasection)
####### dont know how to delete particular node#######
$xml.Save($getxmlpath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RemoveChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the XmlNode class:

```
$childToRemove = $javaSection.entry | ? { $_.Key -eq 'org.quartz.B' }
$javaSection.RemoveChild($childToRemove)
```

Note that using this to find the element to delete is inefficient as it has to filter through ALL of the elements with the Where-Object cmdlet. If your xml is going to be large, you might want to look at using XPath expressions with a method like: [SelectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an [`XPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) expression to find the matching nodes:

```
$XPath = '//section[@name = "java"]/entry[@key = "org.quartz.B" and @value = "BBB"]'
$Nodes = $xml.SelectNodes($XPath)
```

Then in order to remove them from the document, you need to call [`RemoveChild()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild(v=vs.110).aspx) on each node's parent:

```
foreach($Node in $Nodes)
{
    # RemoveChild() will return the child $Node 
    # We don't need it anymore, assign to $null
    $null = $Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Node)
}

# Save $xml
$xml.Save("C:\output.xml")
```